# Any way to clear the data of a DataInputStream in Java? (an Android application)

Tags: java, android

Updated:

The project related to this question has changed a lot since this post was shared, actually I highly recommend to avoid using TCP sockets for transmitting images since it makes the transmission slower. I fixed the problem transmitting the images via UDP and compressing them from YUV to JPG instead of using RGB. This makes easier the job of transmitting and reconstructing the image since you don't have to handle each layer of the image.

To know the size of the image I just simply add this info at the first bytes of the UDP packet so if the size is not received properly, the time out of the socket will discard that packet and the communication still working when receiving the next UDP packet.

Since this is not the answer for the original question, I will leave it as unanswered so others with the same problem may find a solution and post it here.

------------------------ Original Post: ---------------------------

First of all thanks for helping and apologize for my English, I'm from Spain.

I'm receiving images from a computer via TCP using a socket. For every image I get the number of layers (RGB), rows and columns of every layer, then the values of each pixel. To collect the data I use a `DataInputStream`.

Usually it works fine, but sometimes I get wrong values of the number of rows and columns causing problems in the next functions i.e. the app freezes waiting for data that will never be sent, or simply causes an index error on the array which holds the data.

So I want to clear the data if the number of rows and columns is too high, but I can't find any way to clear the `DataInputStream`, full of wrong bytes of pixel values.

In addition, I dont't know the size of the `DataInputStream`, because the size is calculated the following way: `Layers * Width * height`. So if I don't get the real values of this camps, I can't know the number of bytes that I have to skip.

Questions:

1. Anyone knows some way to just clear a `DataInputStream`?
2. If not, should I use another type of Input way like
   `BufferedInputStream`?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your problem isn't really about clearing the input stream but more about finding a back after getting out of sync. A common way to do this is to use a [**boundary-pattern**](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) (used in multipart html docs and in mjpeg streams). So if you get lost in the stream you continue to search for this pattern till you find it.

If you really want to skip bytes, you can use [`DataInputStream.skipBytes(int n)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#skipBytes%28int%29) method.

Comment: I tried to use the skipBytes function, but I can't know the number of bytes i have to skip, is there any way to know the size of a DataInputStream? If I skip more bytes than the ones in the DataInputStream, will ignore the news comming?

In reference of the boundary-pattern, i can't modify the code of the computer that sends the images. I will try to persuade my workmate to try it xD.

Thanks for answer, I will try to find a way to know the number of bytes I should skip.

Comment: No, there is no way to know, *a stream has typically no size*. If your out of sync, well, then you are out of sync and you will need a method to get back in sync. Maybe you can start over by reconnecting to the server?

Comment: By the moment i use this method, when i read wrong values i just restart the thread and works "fine", but I0m trying to get a more efficient way than that  ^^.

Answer (score 0):

A stream can by definition only be accessed sequentially. Skipping some data is possible, but you have to know how many bytes to skip. Essentially if your protocol becomes desynchronized and it does not allow for synchronization via special sequences of bytes or similar way, the only thing you can do is to close the network connection and re-establish it.

Comment: When an image is read an showed, i send a message to the computer to request a new one, so its more or less a synchronize way, I can create a new DataInputStream every time I read wrong values, but this will be a stab on the code xD

Answer (score 0):

A `DataInputStream` is designed to be used to send and receive primitive Java types when *both* ends of the TCP connection are using Java. If you're only reading bytes from it, you can just use a plain `InputStream`.

If both ends of the connection are indeed under your control, a better way would be to bundle the data into an object and use an `ObjectInputStream`. Or HTTP, if the image is in a standard format.

Comment: Using an InputStream seems a good idea, i see that inputstream can get the number of bytes availabe, also implements a function to skip a specific number of bytes. I will give it a try and i will post here the results, thanks for the comment ^^

Comment: The number of bytes available is not the same as the 'size' of the stream... it's the amount that can be read by the receiver at the current time.

Comment: Hm... true, i see the best way is use a marker when all data is collected, i will ask my workmate to modify his code.

Thanks.